ELProcessor and CDI beans in WebLogic
In Java I see this class, ELProcessor and a typical usage:
ELProcessor elp = new ELProcessor();
elp.defineBean("employee", new Employee("Charlie Brown"));
String name = elp.eval("employee.name");

My question is: can I execute some more complex code inside the expression ? For example, can I do:
elp.eval("employee.name && someService.check('param1', 'param2')") ?

Here someService should be a CDI bean injected into this code and "check" should be a method that receives 2 parameters. I'm using WebLogic with CDI.

Indeed, the example code above works fine. "someService" can be injected as usual, i.e. using the @Inject annotation. Note: the parameters can be any objects - the ones given in example are treated as Strings, due to the ''. However, in general any Object parameter can be passed.
